# How to pass dynamic variable value within an object string in Angular View

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to assign variable's value from Component to object string within Angular view.

This is snippet from typescript file

```js
@Input() someVariable: string = '';
let someValueFromTypeScript: string = '';

ngOnChanges(): void {
   this.someValueFromTypeScript = (this.someVariable) ?  this.someVariable : 'default_value';
}
```

This is snippet from corresponding template

```html
<div data-dl='{"prop1":"val1", "prop2":"val2", "prop3":"someValueFromTypeScript"}'>
...
</div>
```

I tried using string interpolation but it didn't worked. One constraint is that value to `data-dl` should be string only, so I cannot do something like:

```html
<div attr.data-dl="JSON.stringify value of property">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist on `data-dl` being a string, you could use the interpolation like following

```html
<div attr.data-dl="{prop1:val1, prop2:val2, prop3:{{someValueFromTypeScript}}}">
  ...
</div>
```

On the other hand if you wish to have an object for `data-dl` attribute,  you could try the property binding syntax

```html
<div [attr.data-dl]="{'prop1':'val1', 'prop2':'val2', 'prop3':someValueFromTypeScript}">
  ...
</div>
```

---

Note: The type of quotation marks (single or double) doesn't have any bearing on the values. The only condition is it should be used interchangeably for member variables and string literals.

```html
<div [attr.data-dl]="{'prop1':'val1', 'prop2':'val2', 'prop3':someValueFromTypeScript}">
```

is similar to

```html
<div [attr.data-dl]='{"prop1":"val1", "prop2":"val2", "prop3":someValueFromTypeScript}'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function into component.ts:

```
getSomeValueFromTypeScript(){
  return this.someValueFromTypeScript;
}
```

And then call it from html component into your object:

```
<div data-dl='{"prop1":"val1", "prop2":"val2", "prop3": getSomeValueFromTypeScript() }'>
...
</div>
```